# base64_decode on audio file in PHP

Tags: php, ios, base64, encode

When trying to get base64 encoded data from IOS through API and decoding it in server giving empty response for large files. Means its working fine for audio files less than 5MB only. I can't even identify this problem is happening while encoding in app side or while decoding in server side.

So how can I fix this problem?

Please help me to solve this. All your answers will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How does the server receive the data from the app? It might be a size limit.

Comment: In server side its getting like a POST value. And also server configuration the limit has been changed to 30MB.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Will there be any problem on encoding large sized files?

Comment: Well, I think you need to test things better. For instance: 1. If you encode and decode, without sending, does it work? 2. Does all the data you send arrive? Better still, make sure you always receive all data by adding a size parameter or hash.

Comment: The file less than 5MB are uploading properly. That means problem will be on encoding large sized file. Right?

Comment: Yes, obviously you need to test the larger files, that's where you have a problem. There will be a limit on the size of data you encode and decode with Base64, but 5 MB is not that much. My guess is that it is the transport of the data that is the limiting factor. I cannot help you much further because you have not posted even one line of code.

Comment: Have you seen this SO thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920780/is-it-possible-to-base64-encode-a-file-in-chunks

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm handling the server side only. Means just decoding the coming data and saving in folder (`file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($url[0]));`) like this. I posted this question to understand that the problem will be from server side or the app side.

Comment: Also, have you checked the max upload size and max execution time? I faced this when converting images to base64 and uploading to magento store.

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz Yes. I keep max_upload_size 30MB and max_execution_time 20 minutes too.

Answer (score 2):

```
file_put_contents('audio.mp3', base64_decode($data));
```