# Out of string space when decoding base 64 to PDF in VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, base64, decode

I'm getting the aforementioned run-time error 'Out of string space' when decoding a base 64 string into a PDF document. This obviously only happens when decoding larger documents (164 page PDF in this case) but is there any way to adjust the method to cope with larger base 64 strings?

The code used is below -

```
Private Sub Apply_Click()

Dim strPath As String
Dim b64test As String

User = Split(Application.username, " ")

   
b64 = FinalResult
strPath = "C:\Users\" & User(1) & "\Downloads" & "\" & ConsignmentNumber & " Invoice.pdf"
 
 
Open strPath For Binary As #1
Put #1, 1, DecodeBase64(b64)
Close #1

 
 
End Sub

Private Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()

    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object

    
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = strData
    DecodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

   
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe try a different approach? Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/170018/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams Still getting the same error, seems like its just too big. Is there a way to decode individual chunks?

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920780/is-it-possible-to-base64-encode-a-file-in-chunks  It's possible but I'm not sure you'll find a ready-made VBA version of that.  Here's a thread with a good explanation of how B64 encoding works - https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?781231-HELP-Base64-(VBA)-simple-function

Comment: I would guess you should be able to chunk the b64 string into sections (where each section is a multiple of 4 characters), and decode each section, appending the result to the binary output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me.  You can base64 encode/decode  in chunks, as long as you use a multiple of 3 bytes going in, and 4 characters the other way.

I was able to repeatedly encode/decode a >200MB file with no errors, but it's not very fast (decode is slower than encode).

```vb
Option Explicit

'Show a round-trip encode/decode for a binary file to base64 .dat file and back...
'Add a VB Project reference to the ADODB object library.
Sub Base64RoundTrip()
    
    Const BYTESCHUNK As Long = 1800000
    Const B64CHUNK As Long = 2048000
    
    Dim bytes() As Byte, inBytes, b64 As String, diff As Long, inFile As String, outFile As String
    Dim folder As String, streamIn As ADODB.stream, streamOut As ADODB.stream, datFile As String
    
    folder = "C:\Temp\B64\"           'all files are here
    datFile = folder & "b64.dat"      'for the Base64-encoded content
    inFile = folder & "test.pdf"      'the file being encoded
    outFile = folder & "test 2.pdf"   'round-trip output file
    
    '### Encode process ###
    KillIfExists datFile
    
    Set streamIn = New ADODB.stream
    With streamIn
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile inFile
    End With
    
    Set streamOut = New ADODB.stream
    With streamOut
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
    End With
    
    Do
        'Read the file to be encoded in chunks, and append the
        '   base 64-encoded text to the .dat file
        inBytes = streamIn.Read(BYTESCHUNK)
        If IsNull(inBytes) Then Exit Do
        streamOut.WriteText EncodeBase64(inBytes)
    Loop
    streamIn.Close
    streamOut.SaveToFile datFile
    streamOut.Close
    Debug.Print "encoded"
    'done creating B64 file
    
    
    '### Decode process - read in the B64 file and decode in chunks ###
    Set streamIn = New ADODB.stream
    With streamIn
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .LoadFromFile datFile
    End With
    
    Set streamOut = New ADODB.stream
    With streamOut
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
    End With
    
    KillIfExists outFile
    
    Do
        If Not streamIn.EOS Then
            b64 = b64 & streamIn.ReadText(B64CHUNK * 1.05) 'padding for vbLf replacement
            b64 = Replace(b64, vbLf, "") 'remove any newlines
        Else
            Debug.Print "EOS" 'no more file content
        End If
        
        bytes = DecodeBase64(Left(b64, B64CHUNK)) 'convert first B64CHUNK characters
        streamOut.Write bytes                     'write to output stream
        diff = Len(b64) - B64CHUNK
        b64 = Right(b64, IIf(diff < 0, 0, diff))  'remove the part we just encoded
        If Len(b64) = 0 Then Exit Do              'out of text to encode...
    Loop

    streamIn.Close
    streamOut.SaveToFile outFile
    streamOut.Close
    Debug.Print "decoded"
    
End Sub

Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .Text = strData
        DecodeBase64 = .nodeTypedValue
    End With
End Function

Function EncodeBase64(bytes) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = bytes
        EncodeBase64 = .Text
    End With
End Function

'kill a file: ignore error if it doesn't exist
Sub KillIfExists(fPath As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill fPath
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know VBA is not VBS but it is basically a one-line command in Windows CMD shell and decode is easier than encode. But for testing we need to use both.

So for those looking to use VB methods (awkward use of Windows command line "quotes")

This works for encoding say a PDF to base64, however like OP question
HAS AN UPPER LIMIT. EncodeToFile returned Arithmetic result exceeded 32 bits. 0x80070216 (WIN32: 534 ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW)

However smaller files under 70 MB are not a problem.

`Input Length = 71384621 Output Length = 98153912 CertUtil: -encode command completed successfully.`

So with this method that seems to be a "string" related limitation. (There is a smaller and better way but for "native system" let's run with this. (It takes about 5 seconds).

```
Dim objFSO, WShell, FileToRead, FileToWrite, myCMD, test
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 FileToRead = """C:\test\test.pdf"""
 FileToWrite = """C:\test\test.b64"""
 myCMD = "%comspec% /S /C ""%windir%\System32\certutil.exe -f -encode " & FileToRead & " %tmp%\_- &&findstr /v ""ATE---"" %tmp%\_- > " & FileToWrite & " &&del %tmp%\_- "" "
'test = msgbox (myCMD, 48)
WShell.Run myCMD
```

We now need to do what the OP requires and check the converse result is good for decode big files. (Again about 5 seconds)

```
Dim objFSO, WShell, FileToRead, FileToWrite, myCMD, test
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 FileToRead = """C:\test\test.b64"""
 FileToWrite = """C:\test\decoded.pdf"""
 myCMD = "%comspec% /S /C ""%windir%\System32\certutil.exe -f -decode " & FileToRead & " " & FileToWrite & " "" "
'test = msgbox (myCMD, 48)
WShell.Run myCMD
```

Finally do compare,  which since I always say you should not own big PDF was a problem to find a big candidate, any way here is 70 MB (say 12 seconds to encode, decode & test)

```
C:\test>fc /b test.pdf decoded.pdf
Comparing files test.pdf and DECODED.PDF
FC: no differences encountered
```

Now above was a limitation in CertUtil, as a method which is widely bandied about, as the old "native" way of running in CMD but there is much better but slower way using a 7.5 KB `b64.exe` but we don't seem to suffer limitations.

MyCMD becomes simpler as `b64 -e input.ext output.b64` or similar however do be aware it is slower so my test for double size input and thus double size output was at least 4 times as long in time, but then again Base64 files were designed in the 80s to be much smaller than modern overly bloated PDFs.

[image]